# How can I spawn Wither Skeletons in the Overworld?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I would like to spawn Wither Skeletons without being in the Nether. Is this possible without the use of mods?

Comment: short answer is 'no'

Comment: Outside mods and Dinopet123's answer, no.

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking how to make a Wither Boss? If not:

- You can teleport a Wither Skeleton through a Nether Portal.
- I think you can use a skeleton spawn egg.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can spawn any mob in the overworld without the use of mods in two different ways:

1. Bringing a mob through a portal. Hard, but possible.
2. Going into creative mode and use spawn eggs. Easy but can't be used in survival.

Otherwise, you will have to rely on mobs or travel through the Portal to get them.

Answer (score 1):

You can spawn wither skeletons by using the player commands.
 Press / to bring up player commands and type: summon WitherBoss. 
  Once you do that a wither skeleton will spawn.
 You can summon many other things such as giants, skeleton horses, zombie horses and much more. Use [this website](http://www.minecraftupdates.com/commands) to generate the commands to bring up whatever you want. You can choose it's health its armor strength and you can enchant its armor. Play around and you can summon pretty cool things.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are OP if playing on a multiplayer server or cheats enabled if on Singleplayer (if not `Open to LAN > Enable Cheats`).

`/summon Skeleton ~ ~ ~ {SkeletonType:1}`

Note: This is for Minecraft 1.9